# Activerecord select and distinct

Tags: select, activerecord, distinct

What is the preferable way to use distinct with select in rails?

```
Model.select(:column).distinct
```

OR

```
Model.select('DISTINCT column')
```

I checked and the sql generated by both is same, so can they be used interchangeably or does it make any difference performance wise?